# Adding an inset box on a graph

Tags: plotting, graphics, inset

**Question:**

I would like to have a second inset box on the graph below, as a legend for the graph but it's not showing. I tried to do make it work by editting an old example I had from another question, but it's still just printing the graph (correctly) but without the inset box (which should go underneath the box that can be seen)

**Code:**

```
    dataHist5 = {{15, 74}, {33, 64}, {51, 62}, {69, 54}, {87, 47}, {105, 
    39}, {123, 40}, {141, 35}, {159, 34}, {177, 29}, {195, 34}, {213, 
    30}, {231, 31}, {249, 22}, {267, 14}, {285, 14}, {303, 13}, {321, 
    25}, {339, 18}, {357, 11}, {375, 13}, {393, 16}, {411, 13}, {429, 
    12}, {447, 10}, {465, 12}, {483, 11}, {501, 13}, {519, 9}, {537, 
    8}, {555, 7}, {573, 5}, {591, 5}, {609, 4}, {627, 5}, {645, 
    2}, {663, 1}, {681, 3}, {699, 2}, {717, 2}, {735, 1}, {753, 
    1}, {771, 1}, {789, 0}, {807, 0}, {825, 1}, {843, 2}, {861, 
    0}, {879, 1}, {897, 1}};
(*Raw counts in fixed interval. No dead time on first point - +3s to \
all the x variables to include it again*)

glm = GeneralizedLinearModelFit[dataHist5, t, t, 
  ExponentialFamily -> "Poisson"]

ln2 = Log[E, 2]
halfLife = Abs[(ln2/glm["ParameterTableEntries"][[2, 1]])]
sehalfLife = 
 Abs[(((glm["ParameterTableEntries"][[2, 2]])/(glm[
         "ParameterTableEntries"][[2, 1]])))*halfLife*ln2]
(*sigmaT=Abs[t]*ln(2)*(sigmaK/K)*)
k = glm["ParameterTableEntries"][[2, 1]]
\[Sigma]k = glm["ParameterTableEntries"][[2, 2]]
edp = glm["DevianceTableEntries"][[2, 4]]
redp = (glm["DevianceTableEntries"][[2, 4]])/(glm[
     "DevianceTableEntries"][[2, 3]])
A = E^(glm["ParameterTableEntries"][[1, 1]])
\[Sigma]A = ( 
  A*(glm["ParameterTableEntries"][[1, 
      2]]))(*sigmaA=A*sigma(e^a). Where a is Y = e^(a)*e(-kt), and \
e^(a)=A*)

Show[Plot[glm[t], {t, 0, 900}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> Red, Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time /s", 
    "Counts Recorded in the Previous 15 seconds"}, 
  ImageSize -> Large], 
 Plot[A*Exp[-0.00462480948*x], {x, 0, 900}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> Blue, Axes -> False, 
  ImageSize -> Large], ListPlot[dataHist5], 
 Graphics[{Inset[
    Framed[Column[{Style["Run 0", Bold], 
       Row[{"Data Points = ", Length[dataHist5], "/50"}], 
       Row[{Subscript[t, Style["1/2", FontSize -> 10]], " = ", 
         PlusMinus[NumberForm[halfLife, 4], 
          NumberForm[sehalfLife, 3]]}], 
       Row[{"A = " PlusMinus[Round[A], Round[\[Sigma]A]]}], 
       Row[{"\[Lambda] = " PlusMinus[NumberForm[k, 3], 
           NumberForm[\[Sigma]k, 2]]}], 
       Row[{"D = ", NumberForm[edp, 4]}], 
       Row[{"Reduced D = ", NumberForm[redp, 3]}]}], 
     Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], {Right, Top}, 
    Scaled[{1.1, 1.2}]], 
   Inset[Framed[
     Column[{LineLegend[{Blue}, {Style[TraditionalForm@"Reference"]}],
        Row[{LineLegend[{Red}, {Style[
            TraditionalForm@"Experimental"]}]}]}], 
     Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], {Right, 0.1}, 
    Scaled[{1.1, 1.2}]]}], 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["Decay Curve of Phosphorus-30 by \[Beta]+ Emission", Bold]]
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Thoughts:**

I think the problem might be to do with where my brackets are, but I can't see where or what bracket might be wrong or missing.

Comment: When posting, please reduce the example to the **minimum** required to demonstrate the issue and include **all** data and code required for the minimal example to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed some brackets inside the second `Inset`:

```
Show[Plot[glm[t], {t, 0, 900}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> Red, Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time /s", 
    "Counts Recorded in the Previous 15 seconds"}, 
  ImageSize -> Large], 
 Plot[A*Exp[-0.00462480948*x], {x, 0, 900}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> Blue, Axes -> False, 
  ImageSize -> Large], ListPlot[dataHist5], 
 Graphics[{Inset[
    Framed[Column[{Style["Run 0", Bold], 
       Row[{"Data Points = ", Length[dataHist5], "/50"}], 
       Row[{Subscript[t, Style["1/2", FontSize -> 10]], " = ", 
         PlusMinus[NumberForm[halfLife, 4], 
          NumberForm[sehalfLife, 3]]}], 
       Row[{"A = " PlusMinus[Round[A], Round[\[Sigma]A]]}], 
       Row[{"\[Lambda] = " PlusMinus[NumberForm[k, 3], 
           NumberForm[\[Sigma]k, 2]]}], 
       Row[{Superscript[D, 2], "= ", NumberForm[edp, 4]}], 
       Row[{"Reduced " Superscript[D, 2], "= ", 
         NumberForm[redp, 3]}]}], Background -> White, 
     RoundingRadius -> 5], {Right, Top}, Scaled[{1.1, 1.2}]], 
   Inset[Framed[Column[{
       LineLegend[{Blue}, {Style[TraditionalForm@"Reference"]}], 
       Row[{LineLegend[{Red}, {Style[
            TraditionalForm@"Experimental"]}]}]}], 
     Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], {Right, 0.1}, 
    Scaled[{1.1, 1.2}]]}], 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["Decay Curve of Phosphorus-30 by \[Beta]+ Emission", Bold]]
```

and seems to work:

[image]

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!